# How to Remove/Prevent MS Teams account from using an Identify Provider Frow Web Browser

Tags: microsoft-teams

Every time I attempt to access MS Teams from my Browser (Chrome) it keeps on directing me to my old company Tenant ID.

I get the following message:

[image]

Whenever I sign-out and sign back in I get the same message.

Can someone let me know I remove myself from the Tenant?

Comment: For Microsoft Teams product issues/failures your tenant Admin can reach out to [Microsoft 365 Product Support](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/get-help-support?view=o365-worldwide&tabs=online).  For general questions about Microsoft Teams please post your question on [Microsoft Teams Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum?sort=LastReplyDate&dir=Desc&tab=All&status=all&mod=&modAge=&advFil=&postedAfter=&postedBefore=&threadType=All&isFilterExpanded=false&page=1)

Comment: This sounds like  a browser cache issue. Try clearing your browser cache and try it again.